# how can I change element on the list?

Tags: list, haskell

I have a list (first number is id rectangle, second number is width rectangle, third number is height rectangle):

```
[Rectangle 1 33 33, Rectangle 2 23 45, Rectangle 3 34 56]
```

How can I change width and height rectangle with id = 2 ? I don't know how I can implement function modifyRectangle.

My code:

```
modifyRectangle :: [RectangleType] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> IO [RectangleType]
modifyRectangle [] _ _ _ = return []
modifyRectangle x idRectangle new_width new_height = do
    let (Rectangle id width height) = fromJust (findRectangle idRectangle x)
    -- what next ???????
    return x

findRectangle :: Int -> [RectangleType] -> Maybe RectangleType
findRectangle _ [] = Nothing
findRectangle n ((Rectangle id width height) : xs) =
    if n == id then Just (Rectangle id width height)
    else findRectangle n xs

data RectangleType = Rectangle Int Int Int deriving(Show, Read)

addRectangle :: RectangleType -> [RectangleType] -> [RectangleType]
addRectangle x [] = [x]
addRectangle x xs = x:xs
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't modify it, you can just make a copy with different values.

there are a number of approches to this, you could filter out the original rectangle and add a new one (won't keep order) or map a function over the original list that returns the passed in rectangle unless the id matches, in which case the new rectangle is returned.

Answer (score 3):

My take:

```
modifyRect num f = map f'
    where f' rec @ (Rectangle num' _ _)
              | num' == num = f rec
              | otherwise = id rec
```

`modifyRect` takes a function and wraps it into another function which applies `f` only when the numbers of  the rectangles match. Otherwise it just uses the identity.

I find it a little more general and easier to read than the other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Why use monads, etc. for this kind of task? It seems to me that the right way would be to map the list of rectangles through a function which returns the new rectangle if the id matches, and the original rectangle if it doesn't. Note that this will keep the list as-is if you ask for an ID which doesn't exist, and will change all matching rectangles if there are several with the same ID.

```
data RectangleType = Rectangle Int Int Int deriving(Show, Read)

modifyRectangle :: [RectangleType] -> Int -> Int -> Int -> [RectangleType]

modifyRectangle rectangles id new_width new_height = map
  (\ rectangle @ (Rectangle id' width height) -> if id == id'
    then Rectangle id' new_width new_height
    else rectangle) rectangles
```

Examples:

```
*Main> modifyRectangle [Rectangle 1 42 24, Rectangle 1337 12 34] 1 10 1
[Rectangle 1 10 1,Rectangle 1337 12 34]
*Main> modifyRectangle [Rectangle 1 42 24, Rectangle 1337 12 34] 888 10 1
[Rectangle 1 42 24,Rectangle 1337 12 34]
```

Comment: Writing `rectangle @ (Rectangle id' width height)` allows me to use `rectangle` instead of rewriting the whole pattern `(Rectangle id' width height)`. Very handy in pattern matching where you want to assign fields to variables and still define a name for the whole pattern.

Comment: BTW, it's a rather bad idea to use `id` as a variable. Usually, `id` is the identity function `id x = x`.